# Between/over yesterday and today

Tags: prepositions, expressions

What kind of construction should I use to succinctly communicate to someone that I did a total of four tests in the time period of yesterday and today? If I just say:

- I did four tests yesterday and today.

It will be interpreted as meaning that I did a total of eight tests across the two-day period. So how can my idea be expressed? Would the preposition ‘between’ work? As in:

- Between yesterday and today, I did a total of four tests.

What if I want to state the time frame int terms of days of the week?

- Between/over Monday, Wednesday and Friday, I did four tests.

Of course, all of above is just my own attempt at an expression. If it’s not idiomatic please suggest better constructions.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say :

"I did 4 tests over the course of yesterday and today"

using "Over the course" implies that some event was in place. In your case your event was doing tests yesterday and today.

Or if you are still testing you can say:

"Since yesterday I've done 4 tests" (implying the testing is still happening).

Answer (score -1):

I think 'since' can be used here.

'Since' refers to the time period from a point of time in the past and now.

So the correct way to say it is -
I have done four tests since yesterday.

More examples -

I have been to (Name of the place) four times since last January.

I called you four times since yesterday, but you didn't answer any of my calls.

Comment: Please add an explanation as this cannot be used as a good reference.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/63732)

Comment: Thanks! I've just edited my answer. Please have a look at it and provide suggestions if any